# How to send customize e-mail with Firebase cloud functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer, postmark

I want to send a mail once a user is created with a firebase cloud functions, using nodemail and postmark.

I followed this tutorial : [Tutorial link](https://postmarkapp.com/blog/sending-transactional-emails-via-firebase-and-cloud-functions) from Dave Martin

**But keep getting this error:**

> There was an error while sending the welcome email: { **status:** 422, **message:** 'Zero recipients specified', **code:** 300 }

**Here is my code to send a mail from cloud functions:**

```
//Mail 
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
const postmarkTransport = require('nodemailer-postmark-transport')


// Google Cloud environment variable used:
// firebase functions:config:set postmark.key="API-KEY-HERE"
const postmarkKey = functions.config().postmark.key
const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport(postmarkTransport({
auth: {
    apiKey: postmarkKey
}
}))
exports.OnUserCreation = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => 
{
console.log("user created: " + user.data.uid);
console.log("user email: " + user.data.email);
sendEmail(user);
})

function sendEmail(user) 
{
// Send welcome email to new users
const mailOptions = 
{
    from: '"test" <test@test.com>',
    to: user.email,
    subject: 'Welcome!',
    html: 'hello'
}
// Process the sending of this email via nodemailer
return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions)
    .then(() => console.log('Welcome confirmation email sent'))
    .catch((error) => console.error('There was an error while sending the welcome email:', error))
}
```

My postmark.key is already setup in the firebase config... The API tell me the problem is the format I use to send the mail informations.. How could I fix it ?

**Update**

I also tried to modify the mailOptions as follow and still the same error:

```
    const mailOptions = {
        from: 'test@test.com',
        to: user.email,
        subject: 'Welcome!',
        textBody: 'hello'
    }
```

Comment: What if you just use test@test.com fir the From value?

Comment: updated, with your suggestion I get the same result

Comment: You might want to check if `user.email` is null, because the documentation suggests that it can be.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.auth.UserRecord#email

Comment: @DougStevenson I updated my code in the question with your suggestion. I confirm you that the user.email is not null at this moment, it really contain the user.email information and they are formated correctly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Decided to restart from scratch by following only postmark documentation *(wich is really good by the way*).

So here are the very simple steps to send mail from events in firebase cloud functions:

**1- download packages:**

Run: `npm install postmark`

**2- register to postmark**

Register to [PostMark](https://postmarkapp.com/)
- then find your API key.

**3- setup firebase environment config:**

Run : `firebase functions:config:set postmark.key="API-KEY-HERE"`

**4 index.js code to be added:**

```
//Mail 
const postmark = require('postmark')
const postmarkKey = functions.config().postmark.key;
const mailerClient = new postmark.ServerClient(postmarkKey);

exports.OnUserCreation = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
console.log("user created: " + user.data.uid);
console.log("user email: " + user.data.email);
return sendEmail(user);
})

// Send welcome email to new users
function sendEmail(user) {
const mailOptions = {
    "From": "XYZ@YOURDOMAIN.com",
    "To": user.data.email,
    "Subject": "Test",
    "TextBody": "Hello from Postmark!"
}
return mailerClient.sendEmail(mailOptions)
    .then(() => console.log('Welcome confirmation email sent'))
    .catch((error) => console.error('There was an error while sending the welcome email:', error))
}
```

That's it.

No need to download nodemailer nor use a transporter.

Comment: Postmark needs to be installed in the 'functions' folder of a project. If you install it in the body of the project, emulation will work but deployment will fail.